# Graphviz: enforce nonoverlap among clusters

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to generate a layout of several undirected graphs (trees) in the same `.dot` file for a research project; the goal is to be able to easily inspect the trees visually. In order to achieve this, I'm making a subgraph `cluster_` for each tree, see example:

```
graph {
layout = neato

subgraph cluster_0 {
label = "n= 7, tree 1";
nd_93 [label= "1"];
nd_94 [label= "2"];
nd_95 [label= "3"];
nd_96 [label= "4"];
nd_97 [label= "5"];
nd_98 [label= "6"];
nd_99 [label= "7"];
nd_93 -- nd_94;
nd_93 -- nd_97;
nd_94 -- nd_95;
nd_94 -- nd_96;
nd_97 -- nd_98;
nd_97 -- nd_99;
}
subgraph cluster_1 {
label = "n= 8, tree 1";
nd_238 [label= "1"];
nd_239 [label= "2"];
nd_240 [label= "3"];
nd_241 [label= "4"];
nd_242 [label= "5"];
nd_243 [label= "6"];
nd_244 [label= "7"];
nd_245 [label= "8"];
nd_238 -- nd_239;
nd_238 -- nd_243;
nd_239 -- nd_240;
nd_239 -- nd_241;
nd_239 -- nd_242;
nd_243 -- nd_244;
nd_243 -- nd_245;
}
subgraph cluster_2 {
label = "n= 9, tree 1";
nd_380 [label= "1"];
nd_381 [label= "2"];
nd_382 [label= "3"];
nd_383 [label= "4"];
nd_384 [label= "5"];
nd_385 [label= "6"];
nd_386 [label= "7"];
nd_387 [label= "8"];
nd_388 [label= "9"];
nd_380 -- nd_381;
nd_380 -- nd_385;
nd_381 -- nd_382;
nd_382 -- nd_383;
nd_382 -- nd_384;
nd_385 -- nd_386;
nd_386 -- nd_387;
nd_386 -- nd_388;
}
subgraph cluster_232 {
label = "n= 13, tree 1";
nd_20639 [label= "1"];
nd_20640 [label= "2"];
nd_20641 [label= "3"];
nd_20642 [label= "4"];
nd_20643 [label= "5"];
nd_20644 [label= "6"];
nd_20645 [label= "7"];
nd_20646 [label= "8"];
nd_20647 [label= "9"];
nd_20648 [label= "10"];
nd_20649 [label= "11"];
nd_20650 [label= "12"];
nd_20651 [label= "13"];
nd_20639 -- nd_20640;
nd_20639 -- nd_20648;
nd_20640 -- nd_20641;
nd_20640 -- nd_20645;
nd_20641 -- nd_20642;
nd_20641 -- nd_20643;
nd_20641 -- nd_20644;
nd_20645 -- nd_20646;
nd_20645 -- nd_20647;
nd_20648 -- nd_20649;
nd_20649 -- nd_20650;
nd_20649 -- nd_20651;
}
}
```

The `layout=dot` makes the trees appear each next to each other in a horizontal line, which is not desirable when there are more trees than just four (and in the real file there are going to be around 300 trees) -- it becomes harder to find patterns.
[image].

The `layout=neato` produces nicer results concerning the layout of the trees themselves (the layout of the nodes in each cluster is more faithful to an undirected tree -- `dot` produces drawings of rooted trees) and the clusters (the actual trees) appear closer together and can be inspected visually more easily.
[image]

However, the layout produces serious overlaps between the boundaries of the clusters, and the labels (that I need to see in order to identify the trees). Other layouts seem to work better, but are not quite right: `fdp` does not produce overlaps in the cluster boundaries, but produces edge crossings. Layout `sfdp` removes the cluster boundaries and does not display labels altogether.

fdp: [image: fdp]
sfdp: [image: sfdp]

**QUESTION** Does somebody know if there is some layout option, or perhaps some fine tuning of the options `layout`, `mode`, `spline`, ... so that

1. the clusters do **not** overlap (as in `fdp`),
2. the layout of the trees (the individual clusters) is not that of a rooted tree (as in `neato`, not as in `dot`), and
3. there are no edge crossings (as in `neato` and `sfdp`, not as in `fdp`)

The clusters can be arranged in any way on the plane, it is not important for the moment to have tree (cluster) `n= 13, tree 1` close to `n= 13, tree 2` (which does not appear in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- Produce (300) separate graphs in a special directory, say `graphs/`. Clusters probably no longer needed. Assume that the names of files just created have the format `tree_nn_xxxxx.raw` where `nn` is the number of nodes with two digits (`01`, `02`, ...) and `xxxxx` is an index to distinguish between graphs of the same number of vertices; `.raw` is just a mock extension to be able to "capture" them from a regexp `*.raw`.
- Run each through `neato` (or any of the engines). Note: make the output format `-Tdot`. For example,

```sh
for f in $(ls graphs/*.raw); do
    # '$f' contains '.raw'
    f_no_ext=${f:0: $(( ${#f} - 4 ))}
    dot -Tdot $f > $f_no_ext.dot
done
```

- Then, you can use [`gvpack`](https://graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) to combine those files into one (very large) graph. For example,

```sh
function normalize_value {
    n=$1
    if [ $n -lt 10 ]; then
        echo "0"$n
    else
        echo $n
    fi
}
for n in `seq 1 14`; do
    echo $n
    nn=$(normalize_value $n)
    gvpack -array_it20 graphs/tree_$nn*.dot > graphs/big_graph_$nn.dot
done
```

You will probably want to run some experiments with `gvpack` to get a "best" layout.

- Finally, run each `big_graph_*` file through `neato -n2 -Tsvg` to visualize the result. For example,

```sh
for n in `seq 1 14`; do
    echo $n
    nn=$(normalize_value $n)
    
    echo "    Run neato"
    neato -n2 -Tsvg graphs/big_graph_$nn.dot > all_trees_with_nonbip_$nn.svg
done
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the program `gvpack` and the fact that `neato` is a standalone program. I didn't know any of those two things. I'll try my best with your approach!